# MySQL Limit returned rows AND count the number of non limited rows

Tags: mysql, count, limit

This is my query at the moment:

```
SELECT `id`, `type`, `data`, `data_zbid`, `time`
FROM `notifications`
WHERE `cid`='$cid' AND `zbid`='$zbid' AND `read`='$read'
ORDER BY `time` DESC
LIMIT $start, $amount
```

As you can see, I'm limiting the number of results that are returned to `$amount`, a positive integer. But I would also like to know how many notifications are in the table, or how many results would have been returned if I did not use `limit`. Is there a way of doing this in the same query?

Comment: I'd prefer not to have to run 2 queries as this will be rerun on every page hit.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can write following query here

SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, `id`, `type`, `data`, `data_zbid`, `time`
FROM `notifications`
WHERE `cid`='$cid' AND `zbid`='$zbid' AND `read`='$read'
ORDER BY `time` DESC
LIMIT $start, $amount

It will return total number of entries in the table against total attribute

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `id`, ... LIMIT ...
```

Then:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

The `FOUND_ROWS()` function returns the number of rows the previous query would have returned without the `LIMIT`.

It's not possible to do this in a single result-set, since each row in the result-set must have all the same columns.  It can be accomplished with a stored procedure, since these can return multiple distinct result sets from a single request, but the time to execute the second query as shown above should be negligible.